# How to replace value in ng-repeat if value =="string" else don't display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm trying to replace my data in my table with strings "Yup" and " ": if the string is equal to "yes" then display "Yup" else don't display, Sorry I'm newbie and I saw some solutions and I tried this but doesn't work: `{{ person.value ? "Yup":" "}}` .. Any help please

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.register = {
      value: [
        {value:"Yes"},{value:"no"},{value:"yes"},
        {value:"No"},{value:"no"}
      ],
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
<table id="example" width="100%">
    <thead>
       <tr align="center">
         <th>Value</th>
         <th>Replace</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="person in register.value">
         <td align="center">{{ person.value }}</td>
         <td align="center">{{ person.value ? "Yup":" "}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

Comment: When you use a ternary (`? :`) it converts the values into truthly values, and a non-empty string will always be true, so either change your values to booleans or have have the ternary like `person.value == "yes"? "Yup": " "` even then you'll have an issue as you have `"Yes"` and `"yes"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.register = {
      value: [
        {value:"Yes"},{value:"no"},{value:"yes"},
        {value:"No"},{value:"no"}
      ],
    };
  }]);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
<table id="example" width="100%">
    <thead>
       <tr align="center">
         <th>Value</th>
         <th>Replace</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>            
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="person in register.value">
         <td align="center">{{ person.value }}</td>
         <td align="center">{{ person.value.toLowerCase() == "yes" ? "Yup":" "}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change your values you can call `toLowerCase()` on the value to make sure it's lower case and then compare it to `"yes"`

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.register = {
      value: [
        {value:"Yes"},{value:"no"},{value:"yes"},
        {value:"No"},{value:"no"}
      ],
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
<table id="example" width="100%">
    <thead>
       <tr align="center">
         <th>Value</th>
         <th>Replace</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="person in register.value">
         <td align="center">{{ person.value }}</td>
         <td align="center">{{ person.value.toLowerCase() == "yes" ? "Yup":" "}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

The reason your code wasn't working it because when you use a ternary `(? :)` it converts the values into truthy values, and a non-empty string will always be true, so every value is true and will always be `"Yup"`